# Very Simple C# StreamWriter Program, not Writing to my .txt file

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and programming in general.

I've been reading the Yellow Book by Rob Miles, and he had an example in his book that looked very much like this.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class streamWriting
  {
    static void Main ()
     {

     string filename;
     filename = @"C:\Users\wraar_000\Desktop\Project 1\test.txt";
     StreamWriter writer; 

     writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(filename)); 
     writer.WriteLine("hello");
     }

  }
```

I'm not getting any errors, but it's not writing to my .txt file.  In trying to find a solution to this, I found a couple workarounds, but it still seems like this code should work and I was wondering why it's not.

Comment: Put your writer in using statement and flush buffer of the writer

Comment: you need to close the stream. You should do `using` on it

Comment: Try closing the the stream before your code ends (do flush whenever you want to write anything in the buffers if don't wanna close)

Comment: Commenters, any comments above are answers to the question so you should post as answer instead of comment.

Comment: @Snympi I can't speak for the others, but I will frequently answer in the comments so some newcomer to SO can get some rep.

Comment: @Amy Fair enough. There is a slight flaw then because some of these questions with lots of comments and no recorded answers still shows as unanswered. Not saying any scenario is right - just looking at how the system at large misrepresents the number of answered vs unanswered questions.